# Копирование на удаленный сервер

Tags: linux, ssh

Не могу скопировать файл на удаленный сервер.

В терминале из папки .ssh, где лежит приватный ключ id_rsa, запускаю команду:

```
sudo scp -i id-rsa /Users/macbookbro/Desktop/folder/docker-compose.yaml asinelnikov@51.250.26.250:/home/asinelnikov/
```

Но выходит ошибка

```
Warning: Identity file id-rsa not accessible: No such file or directory.
asinelnikov@51.250.26.250: Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection
```

Файл ключа присутствует

```
macbookbros-MacBook-Pro:.ssh macbookbro$ ls -a
.       ..      id_rsa      id_rsa.pub  known_hosts
```

Так же пробовал без указания приватного ключа, но так же отказано в доступе

```
sudo scp /Users/macbookbro/Desktop/folder/docker-compose.yaml asinelnikov@51.250.26.250:/home/asinelnikov/
Password:
asinelnikov@51.250.26.250: Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection
```

При этом подключение по ssh к удаленному серверу проходит без проблем

```
ssh asinelnikov@51.250.26.250
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что делаю не так. Как правильно скопировать файлы вручную на удаленный сервер?

Comment: `s/sudo scp/scp/`

Comment: нужно посмотреть /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Comment: `id-rsa` и `id_rsa` это разные вещи

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо! Все получилось, не заметил, что не правильно ключ прописал.